# Convert({document}.field) is not supported

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have base interface and class that look like this:

```
public interface IProblemBase
{
    ProblemType ProblemType { get; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ProblemBase : IProblemBase
{
    public virtual ProblemType ProblemType { get; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have two other couple of (interface-class) that implement interface and inherit from class shown above.

I have defined collection like this:

```
mongoCollection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection<IProblemBase>("Problems");
```

When I insert document into this collection, field "_t" is added in the document and I want it to be.

[image]

The problem I have is that when I retrieve data like this:

```
return mongoCollection.Find(x => x.ProblemType == type).FirstOrDefault();
```

The exception is thrown:

[image]

I solve this by adding this attribute:

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(ImpliedImplementationInterfaceSerializer<IProblemBase, ProblemBase>))]
public interface IProblemBase
{
    ProblemType ProblemType { get; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

But, than "_t" is not added in document and I only can get data defined by IProblmBase.

How can this problem solved?

[I have created small console application to demonstrate the problem.](https://github.com/alexandermujirishvili/MongoProblem)

Comment: Have you considered to threat your collection as a collection of base class documents? `IMongoCollection<ProblemBase> mongoCollection`,  i think, everything will work fine for you in that case. Indeed the way MongoDriver is dealing with interface in your case is not clearly for me :)